# Discord Unable To Remove App In Discord Developer Portal

Tags: discord

I created an application. I use it and now I want to delete it but I can't. I reloaded the site but it still doesn't work.

Here is the picture:

[image]

Comment: Please reach out Discord support. SO doesn't support discord.
 P.S seems you have space at the end of bot name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the reason is that there is an extra space in the name.